# I need help finding my memory leak using MAT

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I'm using the MAT to compare two heap dumps. I've been taking a heap dump each day and it's growing by about 200 megs each day. I think the leak is associated with java.util.zip because of what the table shows and also because we added a new process recently that zips and unzips a lot of files. (see image)

[image: Heap dump histogram compare]

At this point I open the dominator and filtered for .*Inflater*. That produced a large list of java.util.zip.Inflater. Now I want to see what's holding these open so I picked one and ran the Path to GC root excluding weak and soft references (see image).

[image: GC Root]

It looks like this has to do with the jar inflation and nothing to do with my process. At this point I'm stuck and need some suggestions.

EDIT 1

Sean asked about the ThreadLocals. If you look at the dominator_tree with no filter you see that java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks is 58% of the heap. If I expand some of those entries you can see that they seem to be in the ThreadLocalMap. How would I find what put them there?

[image]

EDIT 2

Sean's comment put me on the correct track. I'm using Glassfish v 2.0 and it has a [memory leak](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-14199). It continually creates new LogManagers and adds them to the ApplicationShutdownHooks collection.

I worked around the issue by cracking open the ApplicationShutdownHooks and manually removing the objects from the collection.

Comment: Do all of the instances' paths to the GC root look like this?  It could be this isn't a representative sample.

Comment: There are 16k instances so it's possible that some are different. I've looked at a few and their the same. Does anyone know why my images aren't showing?

Comment: At any point are you putting ThreadLocal variables in a hashtable? 420k ThreadLocal's active at once seems really high

Comment: @Sean - If I am, I'm not aware of it. However, I agree that it does seem high. In fact it all seems high and if I compare each day to the previous they all look similar so something is growing out of control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sean's comment put me on the correct track. I'm using Glassfish v 2.0 and it has a memory leak. It continually creates new LogManagers and adds them to the ApplicationShutdownHooks collection.

I worked around the issue by cracking open the ApplicationShutdownHooks and manually removing the objects from the collection.